# Does a browser need access to the Internet to browse an internal secured site with SSL?

Tags: ssl, iis, asp.net-web-api, browser, ssl-certificate

I have a secured website using a Network Solutions SSL cert. The website can be accessed from computers in environments in my company which have access to the Internet. (IIS redirects http calls to https). I have a browser in a locked down environment trying to access the same  website using https. The locked down environment doesn't have access to the Internet but ports 80 and 443 are open to the website's server and I verified responses from telneting to ports 80 & 443. (not related to the error anyways). The IIS server has access to the Internet.

The response in IE is shown below. 
Is the IE problem in that it doesn't have Internet access and so it can't connect to Network Solutions (NS) for verification or is it because of maybe missing root cert for NS? NS is a known authority so this is unlikely.
(I am troubleshooting WebAPI calls using https in case someone decides this is not a programming question. I have to make IE work correctly on the same machine before I look at the webapi stuff)

[image]

Comment: If you believe the error message then the problem is almost certainly a missing root certificate, which you can easily check on your own. So did you?

Comment: I will. I still want to know if the browser needs access to the Internet as I was told it does and need to confirm this if a valid requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;TR: usually no internet access is  needed to check the certificate on internal sites, but there are some edge cases.

There is no internet needed to access an internal site which has a certificate signed by an internal CA. There is also no internet access needed in most cases if the internal site has a certificate signed by a common public (i.e. external CA). There might be a slowdown in this case since it might try to check online for revocation information but in most cases it will just continue if it cannot reach the server for revocation checks. It might fail if the certificate is an EV certificate or if the browser is configured to do more strict revocation checks than usual.

But in your case it shows that the certificate was issued by an unknown CA. This means either the root CA for this certificate is not known at all on your system or the server failed to send the intermediate certificates required to build the trust path to the root CA. In the last case some browsers are able to work around such broken configuration by downloading the missing intermediate certificates from the internet - which of course requires internet access then. In the first case (missing root CA) an update of the root CA store could help which Microsoft browsers might do in the background if they have internet access.